# ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'sklearn.utils._testing'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.utils._testing import ignore_warnings

ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'sklearn.utils._testing'
```

How Could I solve this problem? My sklearn version is 0.21.3

Comment: try `from sklearn.utils.testing import ignore_warnings`

Answer (score 8):

In version 0.21.3: `sklearn.utils.testing`

```
from sklearn.utils.testing import ignore_warnings
```

In version 0.24.1 or later ([link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/_testing.py)):  `sklearn.utils._testing` (with underscore)

```
from sklearn.utils._testing import ignore_warnings
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils.testing'`

```
import sklearn
estimators = sklearn.utils.all_estimators(type_filter=None)
for name, class_ in estimators:
    if hasattr(class_, 'predict_proba'):
        print(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those facing the following error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named sklearn.utils.testing`, an alternative solution to that of @desertnaut would be to load from the root rather than from testing:

`from sklearn.utils import all_estimators`

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned by @ywbaek, the following import fixes this problem for **Scikit-learn version: 0.21.3**:

```
from sklearn.utils.testing import ignore_warnings
```

`sklearn.utils._testing` may be introduced in a later version (as observed from [SK Github Repo](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/utils/_testing.py))